# Nightmare at 20,000 Feet: which airplane?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

In several of the still images from the Twilight Zone episode "Nightmare at 20,000 Feet" (the one with William Shatner and the gremlin), the window of the plane looks unusually square when compared to modern planes.

What type of plane does the story take place in? What type of plane (if any) was used to film the story?

Comment: This question is a perfect candidate for visuals in order to have our members look directly at what you are talking about without having to do research just to understand the question fully. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

According to IMDB's [goof section for this episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734600/trivia?tab=gf&ref_=tt_trv_gf):

> "The plane from the outside appeared to be a twin-engined Convair
>   240/340/440, but from the inside was a four-engined DC-6 or DC-7."